# How do I access a list in a list

Tags: python, list

How do I access values within a list of lists?
My list:
`list_ = [[Bob, 13, 156], [Jonny, 24, 180]]`

Say I want to find out the person with an age of 18 and above, and if I do, how do I print out if one is younger or older.

I have tried using `for loops`, but it isn't working for me.

Comment: [Lists and Tuples in Python](https://realpython.com/python-lists-tuples/#python-lists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to perform an index of the index.

so for example in nested list

```
              [0]                 [1]
          [0]   [1]  [2]     [0]    [1]  [2]
list = [['Bob', 13 ,156], ['Jonny', 24, 180]]

list[0][0] = 'Bob'
list[1][2] = 180
```

Looping through is the same
for example

```
for i in list:
    age = i[1]
    if age > 18:
        print("Age is greater than 18", i)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```py
ls = [["Bob", 13 ,156], ["Jonny", 24, 180]]

## this line loops through the ls and unpack the 3 values to variable names
## name, age and value. condition "if age>=18" filters user matching the condition  
_18_or_above = [name for name, age, value in ls if age>=18]

print(_18_or_above)

## this lines sort the list by first element of list item which is age
sorted_by_age = sorted(ls, key=lambda x: x[1])

print(sorted_user)
```

Comment: could you try make it simpler please. I only started python 9 months ago.

Comment: @Anonymousisme have added comment plz check

Answer (score 0):

If you have identical length of list within list then below solution is work

```
for x in enumerate (list):
    if x[1] >= 18:
        print(x[0])
```

List comprehension single line code

```
[x[0] for x in list if x[1] >= 18]
```

Answer (score 0):

### pandas is the best way to organize your data

- [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/)
- `strings`, like `Bob` and `Johnny`, must be surrounded with `''` or `""`.
- Don't use python methods, such as `list`, as the name of variables (e.g. don't name your `list`, `list`), as in the example.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [['Bob', 13, 156], ['Jonny', 24, 180]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Age', 'Weight'])

print(df)

  Name  Age  Weight
   Bob   13     156
 Jonny   24     180
```

- Now you can use a Boolean to search the pandas dataframe
- [Indexing and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)
- [Selecting Subsets of Data in Pandas](https://medium.com/dunder-data/selecting-subsets-of-data-in-pandas-39e811c81a0c)

```py
over_18 = df[df.Age > 18]

print(over_18)

  Name  Age  Weight
 Jonny   24     180
```